# Does $\mathrm{SO}_n \cong T^1\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere and let $T^1\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be its unit tangent bundle. I have just learnt that $\mathrm{SO}_3 \cong T^1\mathbb{S}^2$. Here $\cong$ means 'homeomorphism'. Does it hold for all $n$ ?
A well-known method to show $\mathrm{SO}_3 \cong T^1\mathbb{S}^2$ is that one take point $p \in \mathbb{S}^2$ as the first column and $q \in T\mathbb{S}^2$ as the second column. Then the third column is $p \times q$, and this proves to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: The dimension does not match in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dimensions do not match; $\dim\mathrm{UT}S^{n-1} = 2n-3$ but $\dim SO(n)=\binom{n}{2}$.

For $n=3$ since $S^3$ is parallelizable we have $\mathrm{UT}S^3=S^3\times S^2$ but $SO(4)=(S^3\times S^3)/S^0$ (where we quotient the Lie group $S^3\times S^3$ by the diagonal copy of $S^0=\{\pm1\}$).

In general, the unit tangent bundle $S^{n-2}\to\mathrm{UT}S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ is like a twisted version of the direct product $S^{n-2}\times S^{n-1}$ (like how a Mobius band is a twisted version of a cylinder $S^1\times I$), whereas there are bundles $SO(n-1)\to SO(n)\to S^{n-1}$ (pick a point $p\in S^{n-1}$ and apply rotations to it; the fibers are cosets of $p$'s stabilizer). This means, loosely speaking, $SO(n)$ is like a *very* twisted version of $S^1\times S^2\times\cdots\times S^{n-1}$. Indeed, there is a bundle $SO(n)\to \mathrm{UT}S^{n-1}$ given by projecting to the first two columns (as you describe). The fibers are cosets of $SO(n-2)$ (which stabilizers two orthogonal vectors).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was trying to find possible homeomorphisms for $\mathrm{UT}\mathbb{S}^n$. This answer helps a lot.